# wenzhixin bootstrap-table doesn't return any results with server size pageination

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-ajax, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to implement this bootstrap table in my code and I'm having the worst time with it. I get results back until I add the line sidePagination: 'server'. Then I get nothing. The code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table id="itemsTable"></table>
}

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#itemsTable").bootstrapTable({
            url: '/Tests/Data',
            method: 'get',
            queryParamsType: 'Else',
            pageination: 'true',
            pageSize: 10,
            sidePagination: 'server',
            pageList: '[10, 25, 50, 100, 200]',
            columns: [
                {
                    field: 'CampaignName',
                    title: 'CampaignName',
                    sortable: true
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Server Side Code

```
// GET: Tests
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult Data(int? pageSize, int? pageNumber, string sortOrder)
    {
        var list = _campaignRepository.GetAll().Select(x => new
        {
            x.CampaignName
        }).ToList();

        JsonResult results = Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return results;
    }
```

I've spent 2 days monkeying with this table. Please, anyone with experience, any manner of help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[updated below with answer]

I have a similar issue whenever server-side pagination is specified in the options (obligatory code reference to allow JSFiddle reference):

```
sidePagination: 'server'
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/m8e2kk6d/ for a concrete example and https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1281 for the issue I have raised.

Cheers,
Daniel

--

Update 13/Aug/15:

The issues is that server-side pagination requires a different server response format:

```
{
    total: 100,
    rows: []
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I know, sorry :(

I'm new to stackoverflow and it would not let me comment (less than 50 reputation).

Comment: @singe3, the answer is now correct. Would you change the down-vote?